# aggregation: retaining values from the previous aggregation pipelines in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hi how can we retain values from the previous aggregation pipelines.suppose lets say i have multiple collections,assume 3 collections in this case. There may be more than 1000 documents in every collection

```
///collection 1: collection1///
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e58b69b76e00159b4dfd286"),
    "name" : "Dean"
    "type" : ["app"],
    "city" : "cityA1",
 }
 ///collection 2: collection2///
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83263cc"),
      "code" : "A001",
      "day" : "sunday",
      "city" : "cityA1",
      "status":"active"
   },
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5e1efac668c3c811c83265fb"),
      "Code" : "A002",
      "day" : "sunday",
      "city" : "cityA1",
   },
 ///collection 3: collection3///  
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e58b69b76e00159b4dfd286"),
    "collection1_Id":ObjectId("5e58b69b76e00159b4dfd286")
    "handleCount" : 34,
    "code" : "A001",
  },
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e58b69b76e00159b4dfd286"),
    "collection1_Id":ObjectId("5e58b69b76e00159b4dff345")
   "code" : "A001",
   }
```

**now here is the query**

```
  db.collection1.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            status: 'active',
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection2",
            let: {
                city: "$city",

            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$city", "$$city"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ], as: "collection2"
        }
    }, {'$unwind':'$collection2'},
  {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection3",
            let: {
                collection1_Id: "$_id",

            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$collection1_Id", "$$$collection1_Id"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ], as: "collection3"
        }
    },])
```

now this query gives the results from collection1 and collection2 as "city" is the common key but common key between the collection1 and collection3 is "_id" & "collection1_Id" respectively, cannot i use the_id of the first pipeline in the 3rd pipeline ,if i cannot then what is the workaround for this.I am trying to achieve this problem statement. **1:** i need to find out all active id's fom collection1. **2:** then i need to find out all "code" for that city from collection2. **3:** then i need to find out "chainCount" from collection3 if it exists if collection1_id matches with collection1 "_id".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) stage:

```
{ $facet:
   {
      output_collection2: [ {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection2",
       ....
       ],
      output_collection3: [ {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection3",
        ...
      ],
   }
}
```